# Traefik 2 overrides an upstream's MIME type

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to convert a project that uses an nginx router to use the Traefik 2.x router. It almost works, but not quite: a file that is served with a Content-Type: application/javascript header gets converted to Content Type: text/vnd.trolltech.linguist. This breaks the web app.

traefik.yaml looks like this:

```
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    watch: true
    exposedbydefault: false

entryPoints:
  vite:
    address: ':5173'
  goapp:
    address: ':80'
```

docker-compose.yaml looks something like this:

```yaml
    version: '3'
    
    services:
    
      reverse-proxy:
        image: traefik:v2.4.7
        container_name: traefik
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.http.middlewares.autodetect.contenttype.autodetect=true"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik=true"
        ports:
          - 80:80
          - 5173:5173
        restart: unless-stopped
        security_opt:
          - no-new-privileges:true
        volumes:
          - ./docker/traefik/traefik.yaml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yaml:ro
          - ./docker/certs:/etc/certs:ro
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    
      goapp:
        container_name: goapp
        image: vitestuff/goapp
        environment:
          - air_wd=/app/project
        build:
          context: docker/goproj
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.http.routers.goapp.rule=Host(`app.localhost`)"
          - "traefik.http.services.goapp.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
    
        volumes:
          - consistency: cached
            source: .
            target: /app/project
            type: bind
    
      vite:
        container_name: vite
        image: vitestuff/vite-env
        ports:
          - "5173"
        build:
          context: docker/vitevol
          args:
            PORT: 5173
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.http.routers.vite.rule=Host(`app.localhost:5173`)"
          - "traefik.http.services.vite.loadbalancer.server.port=5173"
        volumes:
          - consistency: consistent
            source: ./frontend
            target: /app/frontend
            type: bind
```

As currently configured, the goapp container is correctly served out at http://app.localhost, and the embedded script link with src="http://app.localhost:5173/src/main.ts" get hit on the server, but has the wrong MIME type:  the vite container serves out the file with a MIME type of "application/javascript", but Traefik overrides this with a MIME type of "text/vnd.trolltech.linguist".  This not being a legal value for a `<script>` tag, I get a CORS related error.

General background: I'm trying to port [the following demo I wrote using an nginx router](https://github.com/torenware/go-vite-docker/tree/03-add-router) instead.  I'd like to demo Traefik, but alas, I cannot get the damn thing to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here turns out to be with my Traefik related labels. Here is a corrected docker-compose.yaml that correctly defines the services:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.8
    container_name: traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 5173:5173
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    volumes:
      - ./docker/traefik/traefik.yaml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yaml:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

  goapp:
    container_name: goapp
    image: vitestuff/goapp
    environment:
      - air_wd=/app/project
    build:
      context: docker/goproj
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.goapp.rule=Host(`app.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.goapp.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.goapp.entrypoints=goapp"


    volumes:
      - consistency: cached
        source: .
        target: /app/project
        type: bind

  vite:
    container_name: vite
    image: vitestuff/vite-env
    ports:
      - "5173"
    build:
      context: docker/vitevol
      args:
        PORT: 5173
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.vite.rule=Host(`app.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.vite.loadbalancer.server.port=5173"
      - "traefik.http.routers.vite.entrypoints=vite"

    volumes:
      - consistency: consistent
        source: ./frontend
        target: /app/frontend
        type: bind
```

Short version: the new definitions create a vite and a goapp router that are explicitly tied to separate entrypoints. Once this is done, both services get their files out with the correct MIME types.